# ComponentOne's FlexGrid Background Color

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, componentone

I have a WPF Caliburn.Micro application. I used to have there a DataGrid, and here is a part of the code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FirstEntries" Grid.Row="5"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      BaseControls:DataGridExtension.Columns="{Binding FirstEntryGridColumns}"
      CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFirstEntry}">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
      <conv:StatusToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="StatusToBackgroundColor"/>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
          <Style.Setters>
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToBackgroundColor}}"></Setter>
              <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action OnDoubleClickFirstEntry($dataContext)]"/>
          </Style.Setters>
      </Style>
  </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

You can see that each row's background color is bound to Status field value, and a double-click event is handled. Now I am migrating to ComponentOne's FlexGrid, and I don't know how I can achieve the same there, as FlexGrid doesn't seem to know ItemContainerStyle.

Could you please help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C1 FlexGrid does things a little "WinFormsy" for performance reasons and doesn't utilize DependencyProperties, or styles/templates, so you cannot use data triggers to set the row background or set a command to an event like you desire. Their suggestion is to use the Cell's mouseclick events to handle it all in code.

My suggestion, if at all possible, is to go back to WPF 4.0's DataGrid and bind [to an ICollectionView to utilize it's Filtering function](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31).  Linked are many of Bea Stollnitz' tutorials on manipulating collection views.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the ***CellFactory*** class and ***ICellFactory*** interface.
I used this to set different backgroundcolors depending of the item status in one of my projects.

```
Public Overrides Sub CreateCellContent(grid As C1.WPF.FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid, bdr As Border, rng As C1.WPF.FlexGrid.CellRange)
        MyBase.CreateCellContent(grid, bdr, rng)

        Dim infPre As InfPresenterTextEntity
        infPre = CType(grid.Rows(rng.Row).DataItem, InfPresenterTextEntity)

        If Not infPre Is Nothing Then
            If infPre.IsNew Then
                grid.Rows(rng.Row).Background = Brushes.LightGreen
            ElseIf infPre.IsDirty Then
                grid.Rows(rng.Row).Background = Brushes.LightYellow
            End If

            'grid.AutoSizeRow(rng.Row, 0)
            'grid.AutoSizeRows(rng.Row, rng.Row, 0)
        End if 
End Sub
```